# Programmatically add a .MSG file to an outlook folder

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007, pst

I am attempting to create a PST with a sample of MSGs.

Rather than dragging and dropping into the desired folders, does the Outlook.MAPIFolder in (VBA) provide a way to add a .MSG file from the file system into an Outlook folder (I do not want to recreate the MSG, something akin to drag and drop into a folder).

My simple use case is

1. I have a file someEmail.msg on my local file system in a folder say
   c:/someLocalFileSystemFolder
2. In Outlook I have a pst folder say somePSTFolder
3. I want to import someEmail.msg into somePSTFolder such that the
   structure is

   somPSTFolder 
       + someLocalFileSystemFolder 
       + + someEmail.msg

I have managed to recreate my local file system folder structure into the pst folder structure using VBA. Is it possible to import msgs programmatically?

Comment: Perhaps the `.Move` method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: If you add this as an answer I will accept it. However I think the Msg is recreated no ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the `.Move` method, documented here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Whether the message is re-created, I am not certain. If so, you could always simply delete it from the source if you no longer need it.